# ios single AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, global

I'm working on an ios app with uitabviewcontroller that plays some music. I don't want each tab viewcontroller to create it's own audio player. I want to have one single audio player and have all the viewcontrollers share it.

so I have created a class called player, which would initiate avaudioplayer with the song url and plays the song,

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface player : NSObject {

    AVAudioPlayer *theMainAudio;

}

-(void)playSong:(NSString *)songName;

@end
```

I want to create only one instance of this class and all my viewcontrollers share it. I've tried creating it in my delegate,

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

     UIWindow *window;
     UITabBarController *tabBarController;
     player *theMainPlayer;

 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) player *theMainPlayer;

 @end
```

in .m file,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

     //some other stuff here....

     theMainPlayer = [[player alloc]init];

     return YES;
}
```

and then I called it in my viewcontrollers,

```
player myPlayer = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).theMainPlayer;
```

but this didn't work. 
can anyone tell me what's wrong with what I've done or if there is any other way to do what I want to do, which is to create a player object and share it among all of my viewcontrollers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a singleton, in your player.m

```
#import "player.h"

@implementation player

static player *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (player *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising here as you normally would
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)playSong:(NSString *)songName
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

to use this class, just import the player.h

```
[[player sharedInstance] playSong:@"something"];
```

Comment: You totally saved my life! You have no idea how much time I spent on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How did it go wrong? To me it seems the last line would cause compile error. You should add asterisk for class declaration :

```
player * myPlayer = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).theMainPlayer;
```

Other than that, I didn't catch anything. 
But I prefer using Singleton pattern for cases like this.

Reference :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/